# What VCS system does wikipedia, and other wikis use?

Tags: git, version-control, wikipedia, wiki

Given a centralized wiki, what is the best way to track changes? What does wikipedia.org use?

Comment: What do you mean by "track changes"? One of the key features of a Wiki is that it keeps a history of every change, so that's kind of inherent in the whole functioning of a Wiki. Or do you mean anything else?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Changes in Wikipedia is only tracked per page. 
If you need to make the same change over serveras pages, there will be no correlation between them as Git supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All versions of a wiki article are recorded by the MediaWiki software used to host the various Wikipedias. Just look at the History link on any page to see the list of versions.

The MediaWiki software itself is composed of different sub-systems which are tracked via various systems - the main source is viewable at
https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/source/mediawiki/

Bug reports and change requests are managed on Phabricator at https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/

Some developer information is at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/How_to_contribute

Answer (score 3):

Wikis do not usually use a *source code* version control system like Git. They each use their own way to track versions. [MediaWiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) (which is the software that Wikipedia runs on) stores all its pages and versions in a SQL database.

There is a Git-based wiki system called [Gollum](https://github.com/gollum/gollum), but due to the decentralized nature of Git, it's not a "centralized wiki" as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia use [Mediawiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/). Even if I have been a wikipedian for 16 years, I can't really tell if it is the best since I have little experience in other systems. But I can at least say that it is a very solid way of tracking changes.